# After deploying to netlify one page of react project is not showing. Console shows error "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I am stacking with one problem. My react app working on localhost, but having blank page with error [with the type error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6OYJ.png),when I deployed on netlify.
Anyone can help me? 4 more days I can not solve this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGA18.png) here is my code where showing error

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the relevant code you've an issue with. Please add all code and error messages/stacktraces as properly formatted and readable code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { useState } from 'react/cjs/react.development'
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
```

change this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
```

Comment: oohhh brooo, thank you a lot. I did not notice it. I did not know how I imported it not from react. Thank you so much